# Simplifying nested KroneckerProducts

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, tensors

Any suggestion on how to bring a nested [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html) form into just one?
I mean some way of converting:

```
KroneckerProduct[w,KroneckerProduct[KroneckerProduct[x, y], z]]
```

to:

```
KroneckerProduct[w,x,y,z]
```

The reason I want to do this is that [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand.html) cannot simplify the following expression:

```
KroneckerProduct[KroneckerProduct[x, y], z] - KroneckerProduct[x, KroneckerProduct[y, z]] // TensorExpand
```

to zero, but by using the following form:

```
KroneckerProduct[x, 2 y, -z] + KroneckerProduct[2 x, y, z] // TensorExpand
```

it outputs zero as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My naive attempt:

```
flatf[f_, exp_] := Apply[f, Flatten@ReplaceAll[exp, f -> List]]
```

Example

```
flatf[KroneckerProduct, 
 KroneckerProduct[w, KroneckerProduct[KroneckerProduct[x, y], z]]
 ]
```

> ```
> KroneckerProduct[w, x, y, z]
> ```

**EDIT**

But, Ahh... it was already implemented.

```
Flatten[
KroneckerProduct[w, KroneckerProduct[KroneckerProduct[x, y], z]]
, Infinity
, KroneckerProduct
]
```

> ```
> KroneckerProduct[w, x, y, z]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think your equivalence is only true for matrices. For example, consider 3 2-element vectors:

```
{x, y, z} = RandomInteger[1, {3, 2}];
KroneckerProduct[x, KroneckerProduct[y, z]] //Dimensions
KroneckerProduct[x, y, z] //Dimensions
```

> {4, 2}
>
> {2, 4}

On the other hand, [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) already knows about this equivalence for matrices:

```
Clear[x, y, z];
TensorExpand[
    KroneckerProduct[KroneckerProduct[x, y], z] - KroneckerProduct[x, KroneckerProduct[y, z]],
    Assumptions->(x|y|z) \[Element] Matrices[{d,d}]
]
```

> 0